# OWASP ESAPI Logger not working with Java 17/Spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, log4j, owasp

I have migrated a codebase from java 11/spring 2 to java 17/spring 3. However one of the dependencies that weren't compatible was the ESAPI logger which we implemented since we were trying to move away from log4j-core which had that critical vulnerability. What loggers are secure and can be used with Java 17? Is there a way we can continue to use the OWASP logging? Anyone else facing this issue?

Comment: What’s the nature of the incompatibility?

Comment: as a part of spring boot 3 many package names changed from something like javax.servlet to  jakarta.servlet.ServletResponse. OWASP uses that the old package names so it can't be used with the new spring version. more info here: https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/discussions/768

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can add below explicit Dependency

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

which will solve your issue for NoCalssDef Error